# Por que esse array de objetos não está sendo ordenado? (JS | Bot para Discord)

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando fazer um Bot para Discord.
O comando que estou fazendo faz o seguinte (É um sistema de votação):

1-Você cita quem vai ser candidato.

2-O bot envia no mesmo canal as pessoas mencionadas em mensagens diferentes.

3-Você vota reagindo a alguém.

4-A pessoa mais votada ganha.

E estava conseguindo fazer isso, o problema é no passo 4. O bot deve colocar cada mensagem com suas reações (votos) em um array.
Depois ele pega uma propriedade que tem em toda reação,

.count -> Que é quanto da mesma reação foi feita.

E ordena o array de acordo com a quantidade de votos (count), e após ele pega o primeiro item do array (que seria essa mensagem com mais reações).
Mas não está funcionando, o código é o seguinte:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
    //voted_colls -> É toda reação que ele coletou. Ele é um array, e cada item é uma collection de 
    //um objeto.
    voted_colls = voted_colls.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.first().count > b.first().count){
        return 1;
      } 
      if (a.first().count < b.first().count){
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    
    let impostor = voted_colls[0].first().message.mentions.users.first();

  }, 10550);
}
```

Bom, na minha visão tinha que pegar o primeiro item já ordenado e tava tudo certo.
Mas ele não ordena, já tentei vários tipos de métodos pra ordenar.

Essa imagem expressa o comando (quase) pronto (O único problema como já disse, é que o resultado não saí o mais votado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*sim, meu comando é um baguio de among us 9-9*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ordenação está correta e funcionando, o "problema" é que com os critérios de ordenação que você implementou faz com que ordene de forma crescente, porém você quer uma ordenação decrescente e pra isso basta inverter os sinais.

```
asd = [{count:2},{count:3},{count:4},{count:1}]

// Crescente
asd.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.count > b.count) return 1;
  if(a.count < b.count) return -1;
  return 0
})
console.log(asd[0]) // {count: 1}


asd = [{count:2},{count:3},{count:4},{count:1}]

// Decrescente
asd.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.count < b.count) return 1;
  if(a.count > b.count) return -1;
  return 0
})
console.log(asd[0]) // {count: 4}
```

No seu caso ainda é possível simplificar o código.

```
asd = [{count:2},{count:3},{count:4},{count:1}]

// Decrescente simplificada
asd.sort((a,b) => {
  return b.count - a.count;
})
console.log(asd[0]) // {count: 4}
```

Comment: Vlw! Com sua dica e uns ajustes funcionou!